# Find date of third previous event

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Basically, the formula needs to find the 3 most recent completions of a task, then output the date of the oldest completion of those 3.  That is, the date of the third-most-recent completion of each task.

Here is an example if my explanation isn't clear:

```
Date    | Task   | Count of Task
--------------------------
6/30/18 | Task A | 2
6/30/18 | Task B | 3
7/01/18 | Task A | 2
7/02/18 | Task B | 1
7/03/18 | Task B | 1
7/03/18 | Task B | 1
7/05/18 | Task A | 2
7/09/18 | Task C | 7
```

The formula needs to return the following:

```
Task A: 7/1/18
Task B: 7/2/18
Task C: 7/9/18
```

Task A: there were 2 completions on 7/5 (most recent), so the 3rd most recent is on 7/1.
Task B: there were 2 completions on 7/3 (most recent), so the 3rd most recent is on 7/2.
Task C: all were on the same date, so the 3rd most recent is on 7/9.

The formula needs to be able to handle having 2 separate rows on the same date with the same task, as the data set includes such entries.

I think the solution will involve some a combination of Vlookup and sumif, but this is beyond my current skill set.

Comment: Your explanation does not make sense. Why is the desired result for Task A 7/1? It was only done 2 times for that day, but on 7/5 Task A was performed two more times. According to your explanation, that means the 7/5 should be returned, no? And why 7/2 for Task B? It was only run once on the 7/2, but on 7/3 it was run twice more, so shouldn't the result be 7/3 for Task B? Please edit your question to clarify. Don't do that in a comment. Post a comment when you have edited your question, so your followers are alerted.

Comment: I've updated the question.

My apologies for the unclear explanation @teylyn

Answer (score 0):

[image]

*In Cell `C10` write this Array Formula, finish with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` & fill down.*

```
{=MIN(IF($B$3:$B$8=A10,$A$3:$A$8))}
```

Comment: I added clarification to the question.  The objective isn't the oldest date (the original example just happened to work out that way).  Take another shot?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the PivotTable.

   - Highlight the data.
   - Go to Insert > Tables > PivotTable.
   - Choose where to place the table.
   - Check the Date, Task, and Count.
   - Drag "Date" to Rows, "Task" to Columns, and "Count" to Values. And choose Sum of Count (if not already so).
2. Sort the dates (row labels) as descending.
3. Create cumulative sums: In F3, type the formula `=SUM(B$3:B3)`. And extend to H8.
4. Create booleans to indicate when the sum is at least 3: In I3, type the formula `=F3>=3`. And extend to K8.
5. Repeat the dates, because VLOOKUP requires the lookup to occur to the right: In L3, type the formula `=$A3`. And extend to N8.
6. Create the VLOOKUPs. In I9, type the formula `=VLOOKUP(TRUE, I3:L8,4,FALSE)`. Extend to K9

The answer is in I9 to K9.

This solution takes up many cells, but it is a solution that is easy to set up. Note that instead of extending the formula in step 5 to N8, one could instead just change the VLOOKUP in J9 to refer to the 3rd column, and the VLOOKUP in K9 to refer to the 2nd column.

Spreadsheet with Values:

[image: Spreadsheet with Values]

Spreadsheet with Formulas:

[image: Spreadsheet with Formulas]

Answer (score 0):

A combination of my older answer and answer by Rajesh S.

1. Create a cumulative sum with respect to each task: in Cell `D2` write `=SUMIF($B2:B$9, B2, $C2:C$9) >= 3` and fill down to Cell `C9`.
2. Find the max date for each task which was flagged as `TRUE` in Step 1: in Cell `D11` write the following array formula (and press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`):

   =MAX(IF(($B$2:$B$9=B11)*($D$2:$D$9),$A$2:$A$9))
3. Fill it down to D13.

Remark: The tasks must be in ascending order by date for the solution to work.

[image: Spreadsheet with Formulas]